# ASP 0177 : 800401f3 error in classic ASP page

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I have some classic ASP pages showing error all of a sudden.

The error is as follows:

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' 
Server.CreateObject Failed 
/CustCare/mainwebpage_Midas.asp, line 84 
Invalid ProgID. For additional information specific to this message please visit the Microsoft Online Support site located at: http://www.microsoft.com/contentredirect.asp.
```

Now line 84 is as follows:

```
Set MyCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

What can be the reason that is causing this error and how to solve it. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing to create the object for connecting to your database; there could be many causes for this, but the first things I'd check if this is an existing installation (When [KB188289](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188289) would not apply) would be if anything new has been installed or uninstalled (which could cause the object registration to have been mucked up) or more likely you've hit a memory leak in a component that you're using -- using perfmon check the virtual bytes and private bytes of the IIS processes -- if any are above 1Gb then something is *probably* wrong. As a short term measure, restarting IIS will clear this temporarily.